# How send email from jhipster application

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, jhipster

I've developed an application using jhipster. 
I've setted application-dev.yml file with this information

```
mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: **********@gmail.com
    password: ****************
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    properties.mail.smtp:
            auth: true
            starttls.enable: true
            ssl.trust: smtp.gmail.com
```

and everything work correctly.If a new user registers, the activation mail correct arrive to user email address.
My question is, I've write a page contact-me, but I don't understand how send button work, I've, in java backend this method

```
@Async
public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content, boolean isMultipart, boolean isHtml) {
    log.debug("Send e-mail[multipart '{}' and html '{}'] to '{}' with subject '{}' and content={}",
        isMultipart, isHtml, to, subject, content);

    // Prepare message using a Spring helper
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(content, isHtml);
        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
        log.debug("Sent e-mail to User '{}'", to);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("E-mail could not be sent to user '{}'", to, e);
    }
}
```

that I think is the method to use for send mail from contact me form. I need a controller of contact-me html page? 
This is my contact me html page
http://pastebin.com/h8NniSj1

Comment: I also had the same problem. Can anyone help us?

Comment: Is there any sample jhipster project to share?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using JHipster, I suppose you have a controller and service on your Angular front-end.

So, I think you can create a Spring-MVC controller to receive your parameters (TO, Subject, etc..) and call this Mail Service (sendMail) you post in your question.

Please let me know if I've understand you question correctly.

Comment: It's not a good idea to expose a TO parameter in an email sending REST API endpoint. It's a vulnerability which could easily be used to send out SPAM.

Comment: @jannis you are completely right! There must be a service mid-layer to use the data correctly. I was just trying to explain the main flow.

Answer (score 0):

Extend your REST API with a "contact me" method (e.g. /api/contactmes) that you will call from your contact form. The endpoint could accept POST requests with the "contact me" form parameters:

```
{
    "subject": "...",
    "from": "...",
    "message": "..."
}
```

Then you have options:

- it could internally use the `MailService::sendEMail` method to contact you (via email)
- it could save the info in a DB for you to see it later through your admin panel (if you have one)
- it could broadcast the message through multiple contact-channels (e.g. Slack, e-mail, FB, etc)
- etc.